How to calculate a rolling window average per group while excluding flagged data from the lookback?
I have a pandas dataframe - df
    Time    Value   Flag
0   00:30   5   0
1   01:00   5   0
2   00:30   10  0
3   01:00   10  1
4   00:30   15  0
5   01:00   15  1
6   00:30   20  1
7   01:00   20  0
8   00:30   25  1
9   01:00   25  0
10  00:30   30  1
11  01:00   30  0

I want to create a new column ['Result'] that calculates the rolling average of the past two 'Values' grouped by per unique 'Time' unit while excluding / skipping the rows where df['Flag'] == 1 from my lookback. My rolling window size is 2 and I want to shift by 1 (i.e. exclude the current row 'Value' from the calculation)
The resulting dataframe should equal the below:
    Time    Value   Flag    Result
0   00:30   5   0   n/a
1   01:00   5   0   n/a
2   00:30   10  0   n/a
3   01:00   10  1   n/a
4   00:30   15  0   7,5
5   01:00   15  1   n/a
6   00:30   20  1   12,5
7   01:00   20  0   n/a
8   00:30   25  1   12,5
9   01:00   25  0   12,5
10  00:30   30  1   12,5
11  01:00   30  0   22,5

Examples logic:

'Result' in row 8 = average of row 4 & row 2 [(15+10) / 2] = 12,5. I.e. it uses the 2 most recent values for 00:30, while excluding value from row 6 from lookback.
'Result' in row 4 = average of row 2 & row 0 [(10+5) / 2] = 7,5. I.e. it uses the 2 most recent values for 00:30 without values where df['Flag'] == 1.

Data
import pandas as pd

#DataFrame
data = {
    'Time': ['00:30', '01:00', '00:30', '01:00', '00:30', '01:00', '00:30', '01:00', '00:30', '01:00', '00:30', '01:00'],
    'Value': [5, 5, 10, 10, 15, 15, 20, 20, 25, 25, 30, 30],
    'Flag': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Current attempt

Function

def calculate_rolling_avg(df):
    values = df.loc[df['Flag'] == 0, 'Value']
    rolling_avg = values.shift(1).rolling(window=2).mean()
    return rolling_avg


Apply the function and create the 'Result' column

df['Result'] = df.index.to_series().map(calculate_rolling_avg(df))

print(df)

Output:
     Time  Value  Flag  Result
0   00:30      5     0     NaN
1   01:00      5     0     NaN
2   00:30     10     0     5.0
3   01:00     10     1     NaN
4   00:30     15     0     7.5
5   01:00     15     1     NaN
6   00:30     20     1     NaN
7   01:00     20     0    12.5
8   00:30     25     1     NaN
9   01:00     25     0    17.5
10  00:30     30     1     NaN
11  01:00     30     0    22.5

My solution simply excludes the rolling average calc for the rows where df['Flag'] == 1. I want to calculate the rolling average for all rows but exclude the values from the lookback where df['Flag'] == 1.

Here's one approach:
df['Result'] = (
    df.groupby('Time')
      .apply(lambda x: x.shift(1)
                        .query('Flag != 1')['Value']
                        .rolling(2)
                        .mean()
                        .reindex(x.index)
                        .ffill()
           )
      .droplevel(0)
)

Output:
     Time  Value  Flag  Result
0   00:30      5     0     NaN
1   01:00      5     0     NaN
2   00:30     10     0     NaN
3   01:00     10     1     NaN
4   00:30     15     0     7.5
5   01:00     15     1     NaN
6   00:30     20     1    12.5
7   01:00     20     0     NaN
8   00:30     25     1    12.5
9   01:00     25     0    12.5
10  00:30     30     1    12.5
11  01:00     30     0    22.5

Explanation / Intermediates

Use df.groupby on 'Time' and chain groupby.apply.

Apply df.shift per group to shift by 1 and filter out df['Flag'] == 1 via df.query.

Now, get mean per window via Series.rolling + Series.mean.
This gets us nearly there, except that the rolling window for '00:30' is already exhausted at row 6 (because of the filter), thus failing to propagate the same average for row 8 & 10. I.e.:


df.groupby('Time').apply(lambda x: x.shift(1).query('Flag != 1')['Value']
                         .rolling(2).mean())

Time     
00:30  0      NaN
       2      NaN
       4      7.5
       6     12.5 # <- here you're missing row 8 and 10 (same as row 6)
01:00  1      NaN
       3      NaN
       9     12.5
       11    22.5
Name: Value, dtype: float64

That makes sense, because your last window is:
4    10.0
6    15.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64


Solve this by chaining Series.reindex to the intermediate result with the original group index and propagate last valid value with Series.ffill.
Finally, use Series.droplevel to drop 'Time' from the index and assign to df['Result'].


N.B. Not relevant for your example, but ffill would also forward fill values between the first and last valid value if df['Value'] per group has NaN sequences with Flag == 0 with length > 2 between them.

IMO the most efficient approach would be to perform a groupby.rolling after filtering the rows that have Flag == 1, then merge_asof with allow_exact_matches=False to exclude self merges:
# filter out the unwanted rows
# group by "Time", compute rolling mean on 2 values
# sort the index for the merge_asof
tmp = (df[~df['Flag'].eq(1)].groupby('Time', as_index=False)
       ['Value'].rolling(2).mean()
       .sort_index().rename(columns={'Value': 'Result'})
      )

# merge on index, by "Time"
# exclude self-merges with allow_exact_matches=False
out = pd.merge_asof(df, tmp, left_index=True, right_index=True,
                    by='Time', allow_exact_matches=False)

NB. this requires a Range index. If you don't have one, first reset_index.
Output:
     Time  Value  Flag  Result
0   00:30      5     0     NaN
1   01:00      5     0     NaN
2   00:30     10     0     NaN
3   01:00     10     1     NaN
4   00:30     15     0     7.5
5   01:00     15     1     NaN
6   00:30     20     1    12.5
7   01:00     20     0     NaN
8   00:30     25     1    12.5
9   01:00     25     0    12.5
10  00:30     30     1    12.5
11  01:00     30     0    22.5

Intermediate tmp
     Time  Result
0   00:30     NaN
1   01:00     NaN
2   00:30     7.5
4   00:30    12.5
7   01:00    12.5
9   01:00    22.5
11  01:00    27.5


Code
tmp = df[df['Flag'].ne(1)].groupby('Time').rolling(2)['Value'].mean()
df['result'] = (
    tmp.droplevel(0).reindex(df.index)
       .groupby(df['Time']).shift()
       .groupby(df['Time']).ffill()
)

df
     Time  Value  Flag  result
0   00:30      5     0     NaN
1   01:00      5     0     NaN
2   00:30     10     0     NaN
3   01:00     10     1     NaN
4   00:30     15     0     7.5
5   01:00     15     1     NaN
6   00:30     20     1    12.5
7   01:00     20     0     NaN
8   00:30     25     1    12.5
9   01:00     25     0    12.5
10  00:30     30     1    12.5
11  01:00     30     0    22.5

intermediate
tmp:
Time     
00:30  0      NaN
       2      7.5
       4     12.5
01:00  1      NaN
       7     12.5
       9     22.5
       11    27.5
Name: Value, dtype: float64

replace the above code with a 1-line code, it would look like this:
out = df.assign(
    result=(
        df[df['Flag'].ne(1)].groupby('Time').rolling(2)['Value'].mean()
        .droplevel(0).reindex(df.index)
        .groupby(df['Time']).shift()
        .groupby(df['Time']).ffill()
    )
)

same result
